# How to show multiple selected categories when updating a post in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, select, codeigniter-3

hello i am developing a personal portfolio management system with blog section by codeigniter framework. i designed the create post and post updating page like wordpress.

[by defaulted the General category is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gWc.png)

but i want to make multiple categories selected of this post.

*post table* 
Post_title                Category_ids
This is a test post       4,3,6

*category table* 
Category_title   Category_id
Testing_cat1      1
Testing_cat2      2
Testing_cat3      3
Testing_cat4      4
Testing_cat5      5
Testing_cat6      6

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, Please can you replace your images by textual representation of your tables ?

Comment: You can use json for showing the data.